# Loading Android DemoKit ADK App On a Nexus S

Tags: android, eclipse, adk

Thanks to stackoverflow I believe I have finally built the DemoKit App with Eclipse on my Windows 7 PC. Being very new to Java programming and Android programming (lots of C, C++, Perl, Javascript and others under my belt), when the Android Open Accessory Development Kit directions say "Install the application on your device" I am not sure

- a) how to do that and
- b) where the right files are for my Nexus S and
- c) which ones to load.

It's better that I ask this question than not, but please be gentle, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The application that you need to install is located in the "app" folder of the ADK download package. You need to create a new Android project from existing source and point it to the app directory, which contains the source. Build the project and install the resulting apk and install that apk file to your Nexus S.